Qualification of a Patent - Automotive
This is my first post in this forum.
Apologies in advance if this question doesnot fall in this scope of the forum. If not, please guide me on what to do.
So, I have an idea in automotive.
The fundamental principle of the idea is already in the industry now and some automotives do have this within them.
However, I am not changing the principle. I am just proposing the system to change with a different set of ICs/circuits.
Does the above qualify as a patent?
Also, I am not totally confident that whether the existing idea already uses what I am going to propose. But nevertheless, just want to give a try to file the patent.
Please let me know whether my changing of the circuit will qualify my idea to be a patent?

This is fine as a question here. However, let me point out that this site is not a forum, it is a question and answer site.

Novel and nonobvious circuits do get patented even if what they accomplish is not new. Patents are not for a result but for the way the result is attained.

You might want to expand on the definition of novel. Just being different isn’t necessarily novel with respect to being patentable.

I added “nonobvious”. That is what keeps things that are merely different from getting patents.
